# Format a PostgreSQL create_timestamp in React app

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date, timestamp

I'm having trouble formatting a postgres `create_timestamp`in a React app. I feel like it should be easy but I can't crack it.

I'd like to turn this timestamp string:

`2020-10-17T22:43:19.720Z`

Into

`October 17, 2020 at 5:23pm`

I've tried `const createdAt = new Date('2020-10-17T22:43:19.720Z')` -- but the result ends up an object so I'm not sure how to get to the final `October 17, 2020 at 5:23pm` format.

Answer (score 2):

create_timestamp = 2020-10-17T22:43:19.720Z;

```
  const createdAt = new Date(create_timestamp);
  const createdDate = createdAt.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
  const createdTime = createdAt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
```

Then in render:

```
<div>{createdDate} at {createdTime}</div>
```